# Always show output tab as well as results in DataGrip

Tags: jetbrains-ide, datagrip

Is it possible to show the Results as well as the Output tabs in DataGrip - at the same time?

In HeidiSQL I always have the output at the bottom and the result set above it and it would be great if I can set it up the same way in DataGrip. In DataGrip they are separate tabs and I have to click on one or the other but I cannot seem to show both at the same time.

My DataGrip is version 2019.3.2

Answer (score 1):

Now you can only drag-n-drop the result outside and see them at the same time. But after the query will be run again, the tab will open again.

[image]

In DataGrip 2020.1 which is to be released in April, so called notebooks will be introduced, so you'll be able to see results just inside the editor. It will cover your flow, I think.