# Is it possible to show the queries and their table results in DataGrip?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I normally print out both my queries and their results (tables) with Oracle SQL. I've been looking around but couldn't find any way to do the same with DataGrip.

It looks like someone else asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60114320/always-show-output-tab-as-well-as-results-in-datagrip) a while back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *In-Editor Results* button to see queries and tables together in Query Console.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I turned that option on but the console still shows: `[2022-06-09 10:33:00] 1 row retrieved starting from 1 in 56 ms (execution: 21 ms, fetching: 35 ms)`, not the output.